# "blasted across" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't clearly understand a sentence. Could you help me?

> It had taken two days of bushwhacking to reach the site. Six days
>   later, Jensen would be the last man to leave. It was Jensen whom the
>   Rio Tinto mining group, which had chartered the helicopter to carry
>   employees from a Peruvian copper mine to the city of Chiclayo, had
>   reached out to first. It was Jensen who had worked out a strategy for
>   reaching the crash site after it became clear that the ten people
>   aboard had been killed, the debris **blasted across** the wanton ridges of
>   a tropical Yosemite.

What does "**blasted across**" mean here?

Thank you in advance.

Source http://www.gq.com/story/man-who-cleans-up-plane-crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *blasted* is being used as the past participle of the verb *to blast*.  Blast has several definitions, not just as a verb, but the one relevant here is number 17 on [this page](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blast):

> to break up or dislodge (a tree stump, rock, etc.)

The debris from the plane crash was broken up from the force of the crash, and scattered across a large area.  This area happens to be "the wanton ridges of a tropical Yosemite".  This last clause is used to emphasize that the crash was particularly violent, and no one would have survived, as plane crashes where the plane stays mostly intact might have survivors.